# Appending to an object in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to append information to an object in Django rather than update it. I have this database:

```
Database:
-----------------------
ColA  |  ColB
-----------------------
1     |  "Test string."
```

And the code that updates:

```
o = Model.objects.select_related().filter(ColA=1).update(
    ColB = "Entry 2")
```

This will set `ColB` to `Entry 2`. I want to be able to append rather than update. Is there a way I can append the text so that `ColB` will be set to `"Test string. Entry 2."`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but it's a bit fiddly.

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Model.objects.select_related().filter(ColA=1).update(ColB=Concat('ColB', Value('Entry 2')))
```

It's probably easier to just get the item, modify it, and save it:

```
o = Model.objects.get(ColA=1)
o.ColB += "Entry 2"
o.save()
```

Comment: I used the second method, as it looks cleaner and it's easier to read. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
objects = Model.objects.select_related().filter(ColA=1)
for o in objects:
    o.colB = o.colB + ' Entry 2.'
    o.save()
```